# How to convert Raw XML to SOAP XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have some xml generated from the XML Serializer ..How can I convert it to SOAP XML ?...I am trying to do it ASP.NET C#...please help me out

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on the web service or expected XML format.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to create a data class that can be serialized by both the XMLSerializer and the SOAPFormatter.  This likely means you will need a public class with public properties for the XMLSerializer and you will need to add the *Serializable* attribute for the SOAPFormatter.  Otherwise, it is pretty straight forward.

I created a Naive example to illustrate what I mean:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData 
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            MyData data = new MyData() { MyNumber = 11, Name = "StackOverflow" };

            XmlSerializer serializerXML = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
            serializerXML.Serialize(stream, data);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            data = (MyData)serializerXML.Deserialize(stream);

            // We're cheating here, because I assume the SOAP data
            // will be larger than the previous stream. 
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            SoapFormatter serializerSoap = new SoapFormatter();
            serializerSoap.Serialize(stream, data);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            data = (MyData)serializerSoap.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use SoapFormatter it seems it was deprecated i guess..in .net 3.5/4.0

Comment: I guess you need to provide more information.  You likely need to get the service specification (WSDL etc) from them.  You can use WCF to inter-operate with SOAP services once you have the service description.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "raw XML" and "SOAP XML".

What are you trying to accomplish? If you're just trying to return XML as a response from a web service, then just get it into an XmlDocument or XDocument, and just return the root element:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlElement ReturnXml()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fromSomewhere);
    return doc.DocumentElement;
}
```

Comment: hmm...i was actually wanting to send some data over to an url web service...as xml...so i thought i should use SOAP header or something to enacapsulate it...so i was calling it like "SOAP XML"

Comment: What does the web service say it wants to receive? Is there a WSDL file telling you the format? Is there documentation?

Comment: @VJ: that makes no sense. They _must_ tell you what kind of XML they want.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to wrap your xml into a soap envelop ? if so try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053998/wrap-xml-in-soap-envelope-in-net)