# how to serialize an object in soap format and add prefixes

Tags: soap, xml-serialization, soap-serialization

I have an object and iam serilaizing the object using xml seriliazer.
after serilaizing my data looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doPaymentRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Credentials>
<accountId>101</accountId>
<userName>santosh@gmail.com</userName>
<password>1234</password>
</Credentials>
<custFirstName>santosh</custFirstName>
<custLastName>reddy</custLastName>
<ssn>1234</ssn>
<phoneNbr>1234567890</phoneNbr>
<PaymentRequest>
<ncpTranCode>10104587</ncpTranCode>
<tranType>PAY</tranType>
<Payment>
  <tranAmount>100</tranAmount>
  <paymentDateDate>2013-04-30</paymentDateDate>
  <tenderType>C</tenderType>
</Payment>
</PaymentRequest>
 <csoId>203</csoId>
 <csoStCode>8974</csoStCode>
 </doPaymentRequest>
```

But my xml should look like this way

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:req="http://xxxxxxxxxxxx" xmlns:com="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
             <soapenv:Header/>
                 <soapenv:Body>
                 <req:doPaymentRequest>
    <req:credentials>
     <com:accountId>*********</com:accountId>
      <com:userName>*********</com:userName>
       <com:password>*********</com:password>
             </req:credentials>
                <req:custFirstName>Test</req:custFirstName>
               <!-- Optional: -->
                 <req:custMiddleName>Test</req:custMiddleName>
                   <req:custLastName>Test</req:custLastName>
                 <req:ssn>7895</req:ssn>
                 <!-- Optional: -->
              <req:phoneNbr>1234567890</req:phoneNbr>
                   <req:paymentRequest>
                    <req:ncpTranCode>10104587</req:ncpTranCode>
                 <req:tranType>PAY</req:tranType>
                          <req:payment>
                        <req:tranAmount>100</req:tranAmount>
                         <req:paymentDateDate>2013-04-30</req:paymentDateDate>
                             <req:tenderType>C</req:tenderType>
                              </req:payment>
                            </req:paymentRequest>
                          <req:csoId>203</req:csoId>
                             <req:csoStCode>8974</req:csoStCode>
                   </req:doPaymentRequest>
               </soapenv:Body>
                 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to add prefixes like req,com.
I am using XmlSerializer to convert my object to xml.
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stWriter, myobject);

is there any SOAP serialize like thing
............Edited.............
I used  SoapFormatter and serialized the object and converting it to string using
         Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer())

then my string looks weird like following.

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <i2:doPaymentRequest id="ref-1" xmlns:i2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <_x003C_Credentials_x003E_k__BackingField href="#ref-4"/>
          <_x003C_custFirstName_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-      5">santosh</_x003C_custFirstName_x003E_k__BackingField>
         <_x003C_custMiddleName_x003E_k__BackingField xsi:null="1"/>
           <_x003C_custLastName_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-  6">reddy</_x003C_custLastName_x003E_k__BackingField>
         <_x003C_ssn_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-7">1234</_x003C_ssn_x003E_k__BackingField>
            <_x003C_phoneNbr_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-  8">1234567890</_x003C_phoneNbr_x003E_k__BackingField>
           <_x003C_PaymentRequest_x003E_k__BackingField href="#ref-9"/>
            <_x003C_csoId_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-  10">203</_x003C_csoId_x003E_k__BackingField>
            <_x003C_csoStCode_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-  11">8974</_x003C_csoStCode_x003E_k__BackingField>
          </i2:doPaymentRequest>
              <a1:credentials id="ref-4"   xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MemoService/MemoService%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
             <_x003C_accountId_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref- 12">101</_x003C_accountId_x003E_k__BackingField>
             <_x003C_userName_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-13">santosh@gmail.com</_x003C_userName_x003E_k__BackingField>
              <_x003C_password_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-14">1234</_x003C_password_x003E_k__BackingField>
           </a1:credentials>
              <a1:paymentRequest id="ref-9"   xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MemoService/MemoService%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
               <_x003C_ncpTranCode_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-  15">10104587</_x003C_ncpTranCode_x003E_k__BackingField>
            <_x003C_tranType_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-  16">PAY</_x003C_tranType_x003E_k__BackingField>
             <_x003C_Payment_x003E_k__BackingField href="#ref-17"/>
                </a1:paymentRequest>
                <a1:payment id="ref-17" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/MemoService/MemoService%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
              <_x003C_tranAmount_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref- 18 ">100</_x003C_tranAmount_x003E_k__BackingField>
               <_x003C_paymentDateDate_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-19">2013-04-

            30</_x003C_paymentDateDate_x003E_k__BackingField>
                <_x003C_tenderType_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-  

             20">C</_x003C_tenderType_x003E_k__BackingField>
          </a1:payment>
             </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Am i missing anything here...

Comment: why do you want to do this? , have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256887/87956 in the mean time. Still want to you what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What will you do with the XML? Send it to a service? Then why not just use a service referene to send it in the first place?

Comment: My Service will call another Service(lets say thirdparty service).This thirdparty service will take the xml my service will return as an input.and also this xml is stored in DB as it is.There is format for this xml and this format cannot be changed.So i have to serialize my object into this SOAP format

Answer (score 0):

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData 
{
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            MyData data = new MyData() { MyNumber = 11, Name = "StackOverflow" };

            XmlSerializer serializerXML = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
            serializerXML.Serialize(stream, data);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            data = (MyData)serializerXML.Deserialize(stream);

            // We're cheating here, because I assume the SOAP data
            // will be larger than the previous stream. 
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            SoapFormatter serializerSoap = new SoapFormatter();
            serializerSoap.Serialize(stream, data);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            data = (MyData)serializerSoap.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256887/87956

Comment: after using Soapfomatter,I am trying to convert to string using Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());.My SOPA formatted string look weird here.