# Transform XmlDocument into String with no Formatting for inclusion in SOAP Envelope

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, soap

Is it possible to include a complete XmlDocument in a SOAP Envelope?

I have tried countless methods which caused a 500 Server Error when including the XML definition from the `dataFile` so have included a `RemoveXmlDefinition` to deal with that, now I am getting a 400 Bad Request Error.

No matter what I try, I end up with XML with formatting included in the final SOAP Envelope, I just need a string.

```
public string RemoveXmlDefinition(string xmlDocumentInnerXml)
{
    var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlDocumentInnerXml);
    xDocument.Declaration = null;

    var regex = new Regex(@">\s*<");

    return regex.Replace(xDocument.ToString(), "><");
}

var dataFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\XML\\Test.xml");

var debug = "File Name = " + dataFile + "<br />";

var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

try
{
    xmlDocument.XmlResolver = null;
    xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false;
    xmlDocument.Load(dataFile);

}
catch (XmlException xmlException)
{
    var test = xmlException.Message;

    debug = debug + "Error Code = " + xmlException.GetHashCode() + "<br />";
    debug = debug + "Error Reason = " + xmlException.InnerException + "<br />";
    debug = debug + "Error Line = " + xmlException.LineNumber + "<br />";
}

var soapfile = Server.MapPath("/XML/Soap.xml");

if (System.IO.File.Exists(soapfile))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(soapfile);
}

var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(dataFile, Encoding.UTF8) {Formatting = Formatting.None};
xmlDocument.Save(xmlTextWriter);

xmlTextWriter.Close();

string xmlDocumentInnerXml = RemoveXmlDefinition(xmlDocument.InnerXml);

using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(soapfile, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("soap", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    writer.WriteStartElement("soap", "Body", null);
    writer.WriteStartElement("XmlString");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://tempuri.org/");
    writer.WriteFullElementString("xmlDocumentInnerXml", xmlDocumentInnerXml);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

**xmlDocumentInnerXml**

```
<Affiliate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" leadnumber="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id=""><Details><Amount></Amount><Forename></Forename><Surname></Surname><Tel></Tel><Email></Email></Details></Affiliate>
```

**soapEnvelope**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <XmlString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xmlDocumentInnerXml>
        <Affiliate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" leadnumber="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="">
          <Details>
            <Amount />
            <Forename />
            <Surname />
            <Tel />
            <Email />
          </Details>
        </Affiliate>
      </xmlDocumentInnerXml>
    </XmlString>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have listed the sample SOAP 1.1 request `XmlString` is expecting below:

**XmlString**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <XmlString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xmlDocumentInnerXml>string</xmlDocumentInnerXml>
    </DmAppString>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053998/wrap-xml-in-soap-envelope-in-net

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't address my issue.

Comment: What is `WriteFullElementString`? How does the result look like now and how do you want it to look like?

Comment: `public static void WriteFullElementString(this XmlTextWriter writer, string localName, string value){writer.WriteStartElement(localName);writer.WriteRaw(value);writer.WriteFullEndElement();}`

Comment: Have you tried using `WriteElementString` instead of `WriteFullElementString`?

Comment: I have, still same result. I have expanded on my question by showing the xmlDocumentInnerXml and soapEnvelope outputs.

Comment: You could try to change the `WriteRaw` in `WriteFullElementString` to a `WriteCData` call. This wraps the XML data in a XML data block.

Comment: Thank you Markus, WriteCData was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the reason for the errors is that you write the XML directly into the `xmlDocumentInnerXml` in the `WriteFullElementString`-method by using the `WriteRaw`-method:

```
public static void WriteFullElementString(this XmlTextWriter writer, string localName, string value)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(localName);
    writer.WriteRaw(value);
    writer.WriteFu‌​llEndElement();
}
```

This might lead to some schema validation errors. In order to include the XML string as a CData-block and thereby encode it correctly, you can use the `WriteCData`-method instead of `WriteRaw`:

```
public static void WriteFullElementString(this XmlTextWriter writer, string localName, string value)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(localName);
    writer.WriteCData(value);
    writer.WriteFu‌​llEndElement();
}
```